# How to get a field's value from .jrxml via javascript

Tags: javascript, parameters, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've created some reports with *iReport* and i use some parameter in them if i generate a report then i click one of the bar in graph, JasperSoft links me to another report which i configured in *iReport* too. There is no prob. in *JasperReports Server* but i am designing an online dashboard so i am sending and receiving parameters to reports. Also there is no problem sending parameters. On my dashboard there are 4 reports.

If i click a bar in one of the graph it goes another report via URL which i configured in *iReport*, i.e

```
http://myip:8080/jasperserver/.../PARAMETER=BAR_TAG_WHICH_I_CLICKED_ON_PREVIOUS_REPORT
```

Now i need to get that BAR TAG via javascript. So i add a tag to .jrxml file `<fieldtag>$F{fieldname}</fieldtag>`

and in javascript

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/root/ipas_subestats20130731.jrxml", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var value = xml.getElementsByTagName("fieldtag");
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    var fieldvalue = value[i];
}
```

but it doesn't work yet

Comment: can you post your response xml(ipas_subestats20130731.jrxml)?